# Cómo enviar un correo para confirmar una cuenta usando node.js

Tags: nodejs, email

Necesito enviar un correo para confirmar la cuenta luego de que el usuario se registre en mi sitio web, pero no se como se como se hace la parte de:"Acceda al siguiente link para continuar..." Cómo se genera ese link, Si alguien me muestra un ejemplo se lo agradecería mucho.

```
function EnviarCorreoConfirmacion(asunto, mensaje, correo, callback) 
{
    var transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
   var transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'Gmail',
        auth: {
            user: correo_origen,
            pass: password_origen
        }
    });

    var mailOptions = {
        from: correo,
        to: "alternetvpn@gmail.com",
        subject: asunto,
        text: mensaje + " responder a " + correo
    };

    transport.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
        console.log(msg_str_altervpn_ini);
        if (error) {
            console.log(msg_str_mail_error + msg_str_mail_respu + error);
            callback(true);
        } else {
            console.log(msg_str_mail_envia + msg_str_mail_respu + info.response);
            callback(false);
        }
        console.log(msg_str_altervpn_fin);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En las opciones del nodemailer `mailOptions`, a la hora de redactar el cuerpo del mensaje, tienes dos opciones.. utilizar la etiqueta `text` o etiqueta `html`.

Entonces, para hacer el mítico enlace de "pincha AQUÍ para activar" tendrías que hacer lo siguiente:

```
 var mailOptions = {
    from: correo,
    to: "alternetvpn@gmail.com",
    subject: asunto,
    text: mensaje + " responder a " + correo,
    html: pulsa <a href="url/confirmacion?token">aquí</a> para activar tu cuenta
};
```

Ahora en el apartado `html`, puedes poner cualquier código html que necesites para dar formato al mensaje... como imágenes, saltos de linea... etc.

En la API tienes que hacer una función que escuche en esa dirección, y reciba el token mediante `GET` y haga las comprobaciones oportunas.

Un saludo.

Comment: En esta parte: html: pulsa <a href="url/confirmacion?token">aquí</a> para activar tu cuenta, cuando el correo se envia, me sale como texto plano, ningun link sale